# fstab conficuration dualbootsystem

Tags: mount, windows, fstab

I try to mount the public folder from a Windows (11) OS within Ubuntu on a dualboot computer.

What I've already done:

1. Created a folder (as mountpoint) within the media folder (sudo mkdir /media/name of the folder)
2. Added the following line to the fstab:
   /media/username/UUID-of the Windows partition/Users/Public/     /media/name of the folder/
   none     bind     0     0

Result: It worked - but just once. What am I doing wrong?

```
Here's the output of cat /etc/fstab:

> werner@Inspiron-5301:~$ cat /etc/fstab
> # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
> #
> # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
> # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
> # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
> #
> # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
> # / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation UUID=6e7997c0-ea56-4c6d-8957-43f64b94ba0b /               ext4   
> errors=remount-ro 0       1
> # /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation UUID=166A-5416  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1 /swapfile           
> none            swap    sw              0       0
> # Ordner  "Öffentlich" aus Windows einbinden 
> /media/werner/58A26F94A26F7602/Users/Public/  /media/Öffentlich   none    bind    0   0
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/fstab` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422270/edit) to your question.

Comment: You need to add a fstab-entry for your Windows-partition, your bind-mount can not work without mounting the Windows-partition first. Seems you have tried your bind-mount while your Windows-partition was mounted manually.

Comment: Thanks - that was the solution. By the way - managed it another way afterwards: mounted the partition automatically via disks and created a deskop - icon.